# ListView Data Grouping

Tags: listview

Can someone help me up about ListView. I have 2 tables, dbo.category and dbo.files they have foreign key which is categoryID. I want to display something like this [DesiredResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPryF.jpg)

So far what i was gaining is [CurrentResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlVjr.jpg) I want to only display the category as a header then the files will be listed below the header

Here's what i did so far

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceholder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder1">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div>
                <div id="groupPlaceholder1" runat="server">
                </div>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <div style="clear:both">
                <div id="itemPlaceholder1" runat="server">
                </div>
            </div>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="float:left">
                <asp:Label ID="lbCategory_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category_Name") %>' />
                <ul><asp:LinkButton ID="lkPolicy_Title" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Policy_Title") %>' /></ul><br />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
            <div runat="server">
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ItPolicyConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT c.Category_Name, Policy_Title FROM Files f Inner join Category c on f.CategoryID = c.CategoryID Order by c.Category_Name"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```